# Python wrap multiple with-statement variables in a method call

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

I have a method with multiple `with` variables:

```
def my_method():
   with A() as a, \
        B() as b, \
        C(a) as c, \
        ...
        X() as x:
      ...
```

Now, in order to repeat this `with` in a couple of methods, I would like to export it to a method of its own.

Is there any syntax that will allow me to do that?

```
def needed_with_params():
   return (A(), B(), C(a), ..., X())

def my_method():
   with needed_with_params() as tuple:
      ...
```

Which is of course is not correct, but shows my intention.

Comment: Do you need all the objects at once? If not, then `for obj in needed_with_params(): with obj as o: ... ` may suffice

Comment: Thanks, the duplicate was exactly what I was looking for